# Django form in a list

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a template as below (the second column of the table is wrong, which is my question):

```
{% for thing in things %}
    <tr><td>See the lovely {{ thing.name }}!</td>
        <td><form method="POST" action="">
            {% csrf %}
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ thing.id }}">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Kill me!">
        </form></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

And I'm a bit stumped how to make an array of forms like this.  Of course, the above form works great modulo the `csrf`, so maybe all I need to do is figure out how to make the csrf work in that context and then I think I can just look at `request.POST.get('id')` (I think...).

Many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is `csrf`. Use

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

Comment: Oops.  Yes, that would be it.  Thanks much.  And now `request.POST.get()` works just fine, too.